# Why is my uitableview cut off with too many cells ? (swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, height

I have a view controller with an uitableview to display some comments. I use storyboard and autolayout.

The height of cells depends on the content.

When I have many cells, my tableview is cut off, and not displayed fully. But it's correct with less cells.

In viewDidLoad :

```
self.commentsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 93.0
self.commentsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In viewDidAppear, I tried 2 approaches, first with the height constraint :

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

     super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     self.commentsTableView.removeConstraint(self.tableViewHeightConstraint)
     self.tableViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.commentsTableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.commentsTableView.contentSize.height)
     self.commentsTableView.addConstraint(self.tableViewHeightConstraint)

     self.commentsTableView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
     self.commentsTableView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}
```

I tried also with the height of the frame (without height constraint) :

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var frame:CGRect = self.commentsTableView.frame
    frame.size.height = commentsTableView.contentSize.height
    self.commentsTableView.frame = frame
}
```

I have exactly the same result with the 2 approaches.
When there are too many cells, the tableview is not displayed fully.

EDIT

A screenshot. In blue it's my scrollview.

[image: my taleview]

Comment: You can't scroll the tableview?  Have you disabled scrolling?

Comment: I can scroll my tableview, scrolling is disabled because my tableview is in a scrollview. I checked to be sure, the height of my scrollview is ok, the problem is with the tableview.

Comment: Either you enable scrolling in your table view or you need to make sure that your scroll views content size is big enough - sounds like it isn't.

Comment: I add a screenshot in my post. I have increased the height of my scrollview (in blue).

Comment: You need to ensure that the frame of the tableview is set correctly to fully occupy the scroll view content size

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

In my viewDidAppear, I set first the frame of the tableview depending its content size, then I set the size of the scrollview with the height of the tableview.

The solution is to do the opposite, first set the scrollview to the content size of the tableview, then adjust the tableview with the height of the scrollview. And it works !

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.commentsTableView.frame.origin.y + commentsTableView.contentSize.height)

    var frame:CGRect = self.commentsTableView.frame
    frame.size.height = scrollView.contentSize.height
    self.commentsTableView.frame = frame
```

}